# VPS how to know the most site consume bandwidth and memory

Tags: web-hosting, vps

I have many sites on my VPS ,
any way to see all sites bandwidth and memory usage all in one screen from my WHM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes its possible, you can login to root WHM, Search for  View bandwidth usage you will find list of domains with their respected bandwidth limit and usage.